# vscode building of Visual Studio Projects

Tags: visual-studio-code, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to build a collection of .vcxproj generated by Premake within VS Code.  What I don't get is why it works for executing the premake generation but not the .vcxproj builds as the old batch files are the same except they call msbuild.exe with a full path.

---

---

** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.11.17
** Copyright (c) 2021 Microsoft Corporation

---

Building configurations...
Running action 'vs2019'...
Done (160ms).

- Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
- Executing task: msbuild.exe SimClient.vcxproj && "/p:configuration=Debug Static" && /p:platform=x64

***'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.***

- The terminal process "cmd.exe /C "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/Tools/VsDevCmd.bat" && msbuild.exe SimClient.vcxproj && "/p:configuration=Debug Static" && /p:platform=x64" terminated with exit code: 1.
- Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

---

This is my tasks.json there is more but it's just rinse and repeat.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "windows": {
        "options": {
          "shell": {
            "executable": "cmd.exe",
            "args": [
                "/C",
                // The path to VsDevCmd.bat depends on the version of Visual Studio you have installed.
                "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/Tools/VsDevCmd.bat\"",
                "&&"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "Generate Project",
            "command": "${workspaceFolder}/packages/premake/premake5.exe",
            "args": [ "vs2019" ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "Build SimClient (Debug)",
            "dependsOn": ["Generate Project"],
            "command": "msbuild.exe" ,
            "args": [
                "SimClient.vcxproj",
                "&&",
                "/p:configuration=Debug Static",
                "&&",
                "/p:platform=x64"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": [ "$msCompile" ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
        },
        ...
        ],
    }
}
```

Comment: `msbuild.exe SimClient.vcxproj && "/p:configuration=Debug Static" && /p:platform=x64` is not valid. `/p` (or `/property`) is an argument switch to the MSBuild command, not a separate batch command. Instead use `msbuild.exe SimClient.vcxproj /p:configuration="Debug Static" /p:platform=x64` or `msbuild.exe SimClient.vcxproj /p:configuration="Debug Static";platform=x64`

Comment: Even removing the "&&"'s hasn't worked, but placing the command in a batch file and executing that has.  It's just a bit odd, that the "msbuild.exe" command is being expanded to the full path but without the path being escaped properly

Comment: The tasks.json file is read and processed by VSCode. I am also puzzled by the apparent behavior. But if you open a terminal (in VSCode or external to VSCode) and  run MSBuild, the version of the command with the double ampersands would be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to this problem while trying to start a process in an external terminal.  By replacing "command":"msbuild.exe" with "command":"cmd.exe" and moving the "msbuild.exe" into the argument list preceded by "/C" fixes the failing path string.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "windows": {
        "options": {
          "shell": {
            "executable": "cmd.exe",
            "args": [
                "/C",
                "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/Tools/VsDevCmd.bat\"",
                "&&"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Generate Project",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "${workspaceFolder}/packages/premake/premake5.exe",
            "args": [ "vs2019" ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": false
            },
        },
        {
            "type":"shell",
            "label": "Build (Debug)",
            "command":"cmd.exe",
            "args": [
                "/C",
                "msbuild.exe",
                "SimClient.sln",
                "/p:configuration=Debug;platform=x64"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": [ "$msCompile" ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": false
            },
        },

    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

VS2019 is an inherited development tool, but VSCode is actually just an text editor.

If you want to use VSCode to build and run C++ code, you will need multiple extensions and configure everything by yourself.

Here is how I make it work:

**1, install gcc and configure it to the environment variables of the system.**

**2, install C/C++, C/C++ Extension Pack, CMake, CMake Tools.**

**3, Close VSCode and reopen it, this step is to make sure the VSCode load the environment variables and extension features.**

**4, Write a CMakeLists.txt to activate the CMake extension:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(MyProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(cpp-compiler Cpp_Proj.cpp)
```

This is my project structure(Created from Visual Studio):

[image]

When you configure the file and save, CMake extension should auto build the project.

If it didn't build, just go this place and click the button:

[image]

After that, configure everything needed and click run:

[image]

**5, Result:**

[image]

This is my code(a console app):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    //input
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    int x = 0;
    std::cin >> x;
}
```

For more details about more complicated situation, you can do a research on configurations in CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Thanks @"Bowman Zhu-MSFT" but use of CMake doesn't meet my environment requirements.